# Not all results returned by MyBatis

Tags: java, mybatis

I have a query that returns 4 results if manually executed, but only 3 results if executed via *MyBatis 3.7.8* (although it says '4 results found' in the logs). So it seems one gets lost somewhere and I don't know why.

I suspect it has something to do with that there doesn't exist an unique identifier in my resultmap, but in my table duplicates are allowed and these should also be returned.

**Resultmap:**

```
<resultMap type="my.package.Info" id="InfoMap">  
    <result property="taskownerId"          column="v_taskowner_id"/>
    <result property="shipmentUnitId"       column="v_shipmentunit_id"/>
    <result property="sampleId"             column="v_sample_id"/>
     <association property="spread" column="v_spread_id" javaType="Spread">
        <id property="id" column="v_spread_id" />
        <result property="name" column="v_spread_name" />
    </association>
</resultMap>
```

**Select:**

```
<select id="findInfos" resultMap="InfoMap" parameterType="map">
    SELECT 
        v.taskowner           v_taskowner,
        v.shipmentunit_id     v_shipmentunit_id,
        v.sample_id           v_sample_id,
        v.spread_id           v_spread_id,
        v.spread_name         v_spread_name
    FROM
        view_infos  v
    <where>
    rownum &lt;= 10000
    AND v.sample_id = #{sampleId}    
    <if test="taskownerId != null">
        AND v.taskowner = #{taskownerId}
    </if>
    </where>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround than a complete solution:

If the result is a *nested result map* (an object with nested objects) MyBatis needs an ID for every returned object in that map and because of the lack of an `<id>` tag MyBatis can't distinguish between those objects. I currently worked around this with removing the nested objects in my class because they were simple enough so that redudant code wouldn't stand out (they only contain an id and a name).

Now I get the expected amount of results for this query.

As stated before, this is only a workaround, no solution. This is **NOT ADVISABLE** for more complex nested objects.